# How to login using remote user validation

Tags: laravel, authentication

I have a Laravel Application that needs to login using an API call to another remote system.
I have a LoginController with an authenticate function. In this I use a Curl call to the remote system with the entered User Id and Password.  This all works fine and I can show an error when the remote validation fails.

However on a successful authentication, I need to somehow log the user in manually.  I don't have a local user table for this so I need to somehow replicate what the Auth::attempt() function call does to login the user.

Is this possible? Can I have a User Model without a User table?

If possible, what is the best way to achieve this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Laravel authentication requires a user model which implements the `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable`. This does not need to be a model that is backed by the database or anything else really. You can just make a class that implements this and create instances when you need to. You can then use `Auth::login($myInstance)` to manually log in. Note that if this is an external API you should see if they provide any sort of OAuth2 authentication mechanism since processing a user's password for another service is not typically recommended

Comment: And how they can implement userProvider for this “just class”?

Comment: I have tried to do this with a dummy User Class that implements Authenticatable and this doesn't really work as the guard seems to still require a user model for the provider.  So I think there must be some more steps here that I am missing.  Thanks for the answer so far though.